# python / bottle filename and duplicates

Tags: python, bottle

(Disclaimer: I'm discovering python)

With the following code:

```
@route('/test', method='POST')
def index_view():
    image = request.files.get('image')
    img = io.imread(image.file)
```

I am wondering how the files are managed:
If several users are sending files with the same name (let's say a.jpg) at the same time, is there a chance that bottle saves 2 files 'a.jpg' and one overwrites the other?

If so, what would be the strategy to isolate files being sent from having a name collision?

Comment: I wont answer, because Im not a bottle user. However i have encountered a similar problem with my webapp (that uses files functionality) in python flask. What i did is add an md5 hash @ the end of the file name of the user's user name. Supose my username was `mike` and that the hash was `zzz`. Also suppose im uploading a file called script.py. The file i'd save to the server is called `script.pyzzz`. This can be easily retrieved by the original user, because all hashes are the same length, so you could check the last x characters for the hash you would use.

Comment: actually the concern here is not so much tracking the owner of the file, but that since bottle will save the file to disk, I'm not sure if the file names can conflict (using user's provided file name) or if they use a different mechanism to avoid a collision

Comment: whoops my bad, I forgot that there were docs :P please see my edit

Comment: Thomas, please check the private chat, there is something i sent and I dont think SO is notifying chat messages, but it is notifying comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT
turns out your full code doesnt even write to disk,
so there is no overwriting of any files

Actually bottle has a mechanism against that

```
The FileUpload.save method is highly recommended if you want to store the   
file to disk. It prevents some common errors (e.g. it does not overwrite 
existing files unless you tell it to) and stores the file in a memory 
efficient way. You can access the file object directly via FileUpload.file. 
Just be careful.
```

see more at https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#file-uploads

Comment: since I do the call like this: curl -F image=@photo.jpg facedetect.docker.localhost/faces, I have to provide the real filename (which I can't really modify in this case). So, from the calling side, I don't have much flexibility

Comment: Is there a way for me to alter the filename when it arrives on the python side so make sure it gets saved with a hash instead of the original name?

Comment: The code in your post reads an image from a file name parameter

Comment: right: I send the file through curl, and on the python side, I read it, so I am assuming bottle receives the data, saves it and gives me the filename to be able to load it. Since I'm just starting up with python and this lib, quite a few things are not clear

Comment: Wait i still dont get it. Are you saving the image from within your bottle server script?

Comment: The whole python code is here: https://pastebin.com/pB9uBtsi ; Bottle saves the file for me, gives me a filename and I load that file to process it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170439/discussion-between-michael-ilie-and-thomas).